# How does the Py_Initialize() function find the python interpreter

Tags: python, c++

I am writing a c++ executable which can call python interface. However, I don't know how to make this executable program find the python interpreter and run it on other people's computers. In other words, in what order does Py_Initialize() find the local python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Py_Initialize does not need to find the Python interpreter, because it *is* (part of) the Python interpreter! If you can call Py_Initialize, that means that you have made the Python interpreter part of your own program, so there is nothing more to find.

(If you linked it as a dynamic library, there is the issue of how dynamic libraries are found at runtime, but that is not specific to Python.)

Executing stuff on another computer is a completely different problem from embedding the interpreter.

Comment: ”If you can call Py_Initialize, that means that you have made the Python interpreter part of your own program“ Does this sentence mean that if Py_Initialize() succeeds, the executable program I compile integrate the python interpreter?

Comment: You don't even have to call it — if your program compiles and links ok with a call to Py_Initialize in it, that means that it contains a Python interpreter (or that something went very wrong) (though, obviously, if you don't call it, there's not much use having it in the first place!).

Comment: If I compile this C++ program that calls python locally, I hope to use the python interpreter of user's computer when it is running in userf's computer. what should I do

Comment: I think you misunderstand Py_Initialize().  It is for embedding a Python interpreter in your code.  It is not for executing code on an already existing Python interpreter.